Was liquor actually drunk because it was considered cleaner than water?
I am certain some of us have heard the idea that liquor was so popular in history because clean water was hard to come by. But, liquor does not have diseases and thus became an easy way for individuals to drink without the risk of disease.
Is this claim actually truthful? Or but a mere myth?
If so, was everyone just drunk all the time? Did people drink water alongside their liquor?
This idea sounds so bizzar I have to assume it is false but wanted to ask here for a better and more complete explanation on how liquor may or may not have helped ward off disease.

As I understand it, they were generally drinking what, by modern standards, is weak beer rather than "liquor". Even the low amount of alcohol in weak beer is enough to kill bacteria.

Also, the brewing process involves boiling (it wasn't yet understood that simply boiling water makes it safer to drink). For everyday purposes people drank 'small beer'.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

Agree with the dup close, but I've upvoted and cleaned up the title on the theory that someone searching about this particular myth might be more likely to hit this question than the original, so I'd like this a bit more findable (and presentable).

I've honestly never seen this assertion made about hard liquor. Any examples? For beer and wine, sure, take this Scientific American article from 1998 for example. But extending that to liquor makes it even more questionable.

@BrianZ Maybe grog if we count rum as a hard liquor?

Thank you so much to whoever closed this. I hadn't seen the other post, but it definitely answers the question! Thank you all.
